# Strange assert fail on logical and of bool variables

Tags: c++, debugging, assert

Some assertions in my code just started acting strangely, and I was wondering if anyone had a similar situation before. A short code snippet like:

```
#include <cassert>

class A{
    protected:
        bool isM, isN;

    public:
        void someFunction();
};

A::someFunction(){
    assert (this->isM && this->isN);

    ... 
}
```

produces an `assertion failed` result. On the other hand, after changing the code just slightly:

```
A::someFunction(){
    assert(this->isM);
    assert(this->isN);

    ...
}
```

the assertions pass with no problem and function finishes normally. Function finishing normally is the expected functionality, since the `bool` variables are set before the actual call to `someFunction()`.

As an additional question, is there a better way of doing assertions in C++? I've grown up on C, and am still using the C-style assertions. I've just scratched Google surface on this, but found nothing hinting there's anything new.

Oh, and if needed, I can provide more context for the class and the variables if this is not enough for anyone to recognize the problematic situation. The `bool` variables are actually set in an instance of a subclass, while `someFunction` is one of the rare functionalities implemented in the `class A` interface, but since this complicates the question, I will only edit it in in more detail if the community thinks it relevant.

Comment: do you mean the `bool` variables are set before the call to `someFunction()`?

Comment: C++11 brings `static_assert`, which is a compile time assertion. I think it is also available on boost for previous C++ versions.

Comment: the `bool`s are set. I am expecting the assert to pass. It does pass when I put two `assert`s, but fails if I do a logical and and put it all in to one `assert` command

Comment: Maybe you can show how and when they are set? When is `someFunction()` called?

Comment: @EddieEdwards no, single thread

Comment: This smells of a Undefined Behavior which might emnate through literally anything,Can you make a standalone compilabe example which demonstrates the problem.The actual code and code which reproduces the problem is what will be needed to determine the root cause, if not all you would get here is good psychic debug guesseswork.

Comment: Have you tried putting in both, first the asserts individually and then the combined and see what happens?

Comment: @CashCow yes, I've just tried that. It passes the individual asserts and then fails on the combined one.

Comment: @Als I guess I will have to give more context after all. I was hesitant at first because there's a large context (lots of inheritance and methods implemented in various parts of the inheritance tree). I will need a while to dig out a minimal example that reproduces the problem... Digging it out of my code right now.

Comment: @Als you were sooo right... Now I feel kind of uncomfortable for not digging more before I posted the question here. The boolean variables _were not set_ at all. Still, the assertion behavior was so curious to me that I just had to ask. Would you put your Undef Behaviour explanation in to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The one who gave the correct answer was juanchopanza but he deleted his answer almost as soon as he'd given it. Incidentally even if they are uninitialised the behaviour surprises me unless the compiler is substituting & for &&. I guess as a bool should only ever hold one of 2 values it has the right to do that and it is undefined if it has any other value.

Comment: @penelope: Once program has a Undefined behavior(UB), any behavior is possible.There can or cant be a plausible explanation that follows for observed behavior of an program with UB,The standard specifically allows this, **C++03 1.3.24**, *"Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)."*

Comment: @penelope, the standard says it is undefined, and when something is undefined, pretty much anything can happen. I have added a simple example that illustrates that. Changing the optimization level, addinf other data members, or simply printouts, could affect the behaviour. Also note that the booleans don't even take one of the two expected values or 0 or 1...

Comment: @penelope May I suggest that you simply do not let this happen by always using the initialiser list to initialise any members of your class that are not objects with a default constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The booleans are uninitialized. They could take any value. The behaviour here is undefined. To illustrate that, using a gcc 4.7 snapshot on ubuntu 11.10:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  bool a, b;
};

int main() {

    A a0;
    std::cout << a0.a << ", " << a0.b << "\n"; 

    A a1;
    std::cout << a1.a << ", " << a1.b << "\n"; 

}
```

produces this output:

```
121, 0
244, 31
```

or, running again,

```
192, 0
244, 127
```

or, optimizing with `-O3`, a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: what's the difference between the output snippets you put in there?

Comment: @penelope I just ran the program twice.

Comment: ah :) they're completely the same. i guess that was kind of confusing

Comment: @penelope doh! They're not always the same, which is one of the things I was trying to show. I will fix that.

Comment: how are you getting integers out of a bool? Shouldn't c++ enforce them as 0 and 1? Or do they get cast to int on output to ostream?

Comment: @RedX I just tried printing out the booleans in the uncorrected version of my code. They also have non-{0,1}-values.

Comment: @RedX it is undefined behaviour, so I won't spend too much time trying to figure out what really is going on.